# Curl запрос к nodejs серверу и синхронизация ответа от сервера

Tags: php, node.js, curl

Есть настроенный node сервер через express. Запросы идут post методом из PHP. PHP физически находится на том же сервере, что и nodejs. Node сервер обрабатывает данные и возвращает в ответ путь до изображений, которые создал сервер.

Так вот если одновременно несколько человек отправят запрос к node, то получат не свое запрошенное изображение, а чужое. Как этого избежать? Данная ошибка случается редко. Порой мы её не могли вызвать никак даже когда кликали все вместе одновременно, но тем не менее, иногда она случается.

Важно, проблема именно не в методах на nodejs. При запросах корректно создаются уникальные нужные изображения, но бывает, что curl перехватывает ответ на чужой запрос.

Я всегда думал, что CURL ждёт ответа именно на свой запрос. Но получается, что нет? И что может быть, что CURL подцепит ответ на другой запрос?

Может кто подсказать, поможет ли CURLOPT_PIPEWAIT опция или это вообще не то?

Comment: День добрый. Вы ведь понимаете, что без кода мы вам не сможем помочь. Подозреваю, что у вас там где-то перезаписывается глобальное состояние/переменная.

Comment: Нет никакой перезаписи. NODE возвращает base64 картинку и сразу же эта картинка отдается пользователю без доп. преобразований и манипуляций. То есть физически никак не может быть, что CURL перехватит ответ на чужой запрос и искать ошибку?

Comment: Не думаю, что проблема в curl'е. Скорее, в node.js коде.